# Which metrics are printed (train or validation) when validation_split and validation_data is not specified in the keras model.fit function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a TF neural network and I am using the `tf.data` API to create the dataset using a generator. I am not passing `validation_split` and `validation_data` into the `model.fit()` function of keras.

The default values for the above parameter are `0.0` and `None` respectively. So, I am not sure about the metrics (precision, recall, etc) that get printed after `model.fit()`, are those training metrics or validation metrics? According to my understanding, those shouldn't be validation metrics as I am using the default values for the mentioned arguments.

Here's what I am referring to -

`Epoch 1/50 10/10 [==============================] - 6119s 608s/step - loss: 0.6588 - accuracy: 5.4746e-06 - precision: 0.0095 - recall: 0.3080`

[Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) for `model.fit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not validation metrics. If these were validation metrics then these  would have

> prefix with **'val_'** like - `val_loss:, val_accuracy:, val_precision:, val_recall:`.

`Epoch 1/50 10/10 [==============================] - 6119s 608s/step` 
 `- loss: 0.6588 - accuracy: 5.4746e-06 - precision: 0.0095 - recall: 0.3080`

The above metrics of your code are defined in the model [compilation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#define_the_model_and_metrics) which gives results at model [training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#train_the_model) based on the defined arguments in model compilation. Please check the attached links for more details.